# I have this Select form from Laravel collectives and everything I try always returns null on the controller

Tags: php, laravel, view, controller, laravelcollective

I want to return the value on controller but it always returns null and I can't find the issue here.

Laravel View

```
 <div class="form-group">
 <label> {{ trans('content.Keep it private')}} </label>
 {!! Form::select('is_private', array('0' => trans("content.yes"), '1' => trans("content.no")), '0'); !!}
 </div>
```

Laravel Controller

```
dd(Input::get('is_private'))
```

Comment: Did you tried $request->is_private ?

Comment: Yes of course still nothing pfffsssss

Comment: Could you join me here so i can help you https://codeshare.io/2BYogp

Comment: yes sure right now

Comment: Could you please add rest of the form code ?